# MySQL on Windows - how do I set the wait_timeout for connections using named pipes?

Tags: mysql, timeout, named-pipes

I use a MySQL database running on a Windows box, and for performance reasons I'm connecting to it using named pipes.

The (Java) application using the database (through Hibernate) can let the connection lie idle for quite a long time, which causes the connection to fail with the following message:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: The last packet successfully received from the server was 33 558 297 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 33 558 297 milliseconds ago. is longer than the server configured value of 'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or testing connection validity before use in your application, increasing the server configured values for client timeouts, or using the Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem.

`autoReconnect` unfortunately has no effect (and neither does `autoReconnectForPools`), but [the `wait_timeout` docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout) state that `wait_timeout` only applies "to TCP/IP and Unix socket file connections, not to connections made via named pipes, or shared memory".

How can I change the `wait_timeout` for named pipes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how you are configuring your datasource, you may be able to specify a setting like `idle-timeout-minutes`.  If `wait_timeout` were set to 5 minutes, set `idle-timeout-minutes` to 4.

The only two timeout values that can be specified for MySQL connections are [wait_timeout](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout) and [interactive_timeout](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_interactive_timeout).  `interactive_timeout` could potentially apply to named pipes too, if it connected as a client would.

If I recall correctly if neither wait_timeout or interactive_timeout are specified, the default is 28800.

Comment: Thanks, but this does unfortunately not really apply to my setup.

Comment: How's that?  I think you're confused.

Comment: Maybe I am :) I finally solved the problem doing pretty much exactly the thing you suggested, by having my connection pool validate connections before handing them out if they had been idle more than X timeunit. Consider your answer... *accepted*.

Comment: Glad it worked out for you!  This was a frustrating issue when I first encountered it.